# Magento 2: Installing with Redis by Default

Tags: magento2, installation, redis, bin-magento

Magento 2's CLI has a `setup:install` command that will let you generate an initial configuration

```
php bin/magento setup:install --admin-email astorm@example.com --admin-firstname Alan --admin-lastname Storm --admin-password 'whymagentowhy?@###@' --admin-user username --backend-frontname admin.bak --base-url http://magento.example.com --db-host 127.0.0.1 --db-name db_name --db-password yeahright --db-user notroot --session-save files --use-rewrites 1 --use-secure 0 -vvv
```

Is there `[a version of this command, another command, or some third party project]` that will automatically generate the needed configuration nodes for a redis cache and redis sessions?

Comment: Would seem a little counterproductive to offer the driver, but not settings! Still even in 2021!

Answer (score 2):

I just have starter env file what i copy to 'app/etc/env.php' before running the installer command:

```
<?php
return array(
    'session' =>
        array(
            'save' => 'redis',
            'redis' =>
                array(
                    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'password' => '',
                    'timeout' => '2.5',
                    'persistent_identifier' => '',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'compression_threshold' => '2048',
                    'compression_library' => 'gzip',
                    'log_level' => '1',
                    'max_concurrency' => '6',
                    'break_after_frontend' => '5',
                    'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
                    'first_lifetime' => '600',
                    'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
                    'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
                    'disable_locking' => '0',
                    'min_lifetime' => '60',
                    'max_lifetime' => '2592000',
                ),
        ),
    'cache' =>
        array(
            'frontend' =>
                array(
                    'default' =>
                        array(
                            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                            'backend_options' =>
                                array(
                                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                                    'port' => '6379',
                                    'database' => '1',
                                ),
                        ),
                    'page_cache' =>
                        array(
                            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                            'backend_options' =>
                                array(
                                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                                    'port' => '6379',
                                    'database' => '1',
                                    'compress_data' => '0',
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        )
);
```

The install shouldn't replace anything from the env.php if you don't tell it to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following commands to enable Redis (taken from [this page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/redis/redis-pg-cache.html) and [this page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/redis/redis-session.html) in DevDocs):

```
bin/magento setup:config:set --cache-backend=redis --cache-backend-redis-server=redis.example.com --cache-backend-redis-db=0
bin/magento setup:config:set --page-cache=redis --page-cache-redis-server=redis.example.com --page-cache-redis-db=1
bin/magento setup:config:set --session-save=redis --session-save-redis-host=redis.example.com --session-save-redis-log-level=3 --session-save-redis-db=2
```

Answer (score 1):

For a local environment setup, I put into puppet some commands for adding Redis to the local environment.

Two files:

```
<?php // magento-configured-with-redis.php

$file = '/var/www/Magento/app/etc/env.php';

if (!file_exists($file)) {
    exit(1);
}

$data = require($file);

if (!isset($data['session']) || !isset($data['session']['save']) || $data['session']['save'] != 'redis') {
    exit(2);
}

if (!isset($data['cache'])
    || !isset($data['cache']['frontend'])
    || !isset($data['cache']['frontend']['default'])
    || !isset($data['cache']['frontend']['default']['backend'])
    || $data['cache']['frontend']['default']['backend'] != 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis'
) {
    exit(3);
}

exit(0);
```

and

```
<?php // magento-configure-redis.php

$file = '/var/www/Magento/app/etc/env.php';

if (!file_exists($file)) {
    exit(1);
}

$data = require($file);

const REDIS_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
const REDIS_PORT = '6379';

$data['session']['save'] = 'redis';
$data['session']['redis'] = [
    'host' => REDIS_HOST,
    'port' => REDIS_PORT,
    'database' => 0,
    'compression_threshold' => 0,
];

$data['cache']['frontend']['default'] = [
    'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
    'backend_options' => [
        'server' => REDIS_HOST,
        'port' => REDIS_PORT,
        'database' => 1,
        'compression_threshold' => 0,
    ],
];

$export = [
    '<?php',
    'return '.var_export($data, true).';',
    ''
];

file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $export));
```

The puppet line being:

```
  exec { 'Configure Magento with Redis':
    require => [Exec['Install Magento'], Tools::Loadtool['magento-configure-redis.php'], Class['redis']],
    command => '/usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/tools/magento-configure-redis.php',
    unless  => '/usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/tools/magento-configured-with-redis.php',
    user    => 'vagrant',
  }
```

As you can see, magento-configured-with-redis is designed to throw a non-zero code if and only if Magento is not configured with redis, and a 0 code if and only if Magento is configured with redis.

magento-configure-redis.php is then setup to take the data in the env.php file, and add the default redis configuration to it.

It's far from what you seem to be looking for, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

I have a patch for `app/etc/env.php` (smth like this):

```
Index: app/etc/env.php
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- app/etc/env.php (revision )
+++ app/etc/env.php (revision )
@@ -1,5 +1,27 @@
 <?php
 return array (
+    /* SUPPLZ-321 */
+    'cache' => array(
+        'frontend' => array(
+            'default' => array(
+                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
+                'backend_options' => array(
+                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
+                    'database' => '0',
+                    'port' => '6379'
+                ),
+            ),
+            'page_cache' => array(
+                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
+                'backend_options' => array(
+                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
+                    'port' => '6379',
+                    'database' => '1',
+                    'compress_data' => '0'
+                )
+            )
+        )
+    ),
   'backend' => 
   array (
     'frontName' => 'admin',
```

and I apply this patch on deploy:

```
patch ${DIR_MAGE}/app/etc/env.php ${DIR_DEPLOY}/patch/XXX.patch
```